# Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, rubygems, curb

I am trying to install curb 0.8.0 on a Windows computer but I can not seem to get anywhere. I have been trying every website 3 pages deep on my Google search. Please, anyone have an idea of how I can get this single thing installed. I have downloaded curl and extracted it to C:\curl.  I have added it to my path and am running the command:

```
gem install curb -- --with-curl-lib=C:\curl\bin --with-curl-include=C:\curl\include
```

But it doesn't work. I keep getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `curb` gem requires `libcurl`, something that is related to, but different from `curl`. It's the library that `curl` is built with. That missing file is part of the [development version](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=devel) of cURL.

Comment: I installed curl-7.25.0-devel-mingw32.zip but by adding changing my command to gem install curb -- --with-curl-lib="C:/curl/bin" --with-curl-include="C:/curl/include" but when I try to run bundle install or rails -s I get the error again.

Answer (score 129):

If you are on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Comment: I was getting the error for feedzirra gem and this fixed my issue. Thanks.

Comment: only the last library seems necessary:
`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: The current command in the answer generates an error (at least in Ubuntu 18.04) @PierreMichard 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184615/cant-find-libcurl-or-curl-curl-h-runtimeerror#comment48546710_14160148) works perfectly and should replace the current content of this answer

Answer (score 30):

If you are on ubuntu 18.04/20.04.2 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Comment: This has already been suggested in this thread. Please only post answers that add new aspects not repeat previously posted approaches.

Comment: This has not been suggested, and was useful for me. Delete your comment.

Comment: This has not been suggested and was useful for me. The other solutions didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Agreed with Jesse and Hariharan -> this is useful and has not been recommended yet.
If you're running 18.04 this works!

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS same thing: sudo apt-get install libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev

Answer (score 8):

For Amazon Linux (perhaps also centos/redhat/fedora) do this:

```
sudo yum install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are on alpine:

```
apk add --update curl-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

type this to get rid of curl/curl.h error

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

after this you will get a freeTDS error if you haven't installed it previously

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
```

and after this

```
gem install tiny_tds
```

Answer (score 4):

First, update your package lists by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install the development version of libcurl3

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

Such header files are usually packaged in a `xxx-dev` package. In this case `libcurl-dev`.

Usually they also provide "virtual" packages that resolve to latest version of a package. In case there are multiple implementation available then it'll list and ask you to pick the one you want, else it'll go ahead and select the latest one.

```
vagrant@my_box $ sudo apt-get install libcurl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libcurl-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17
  libcurl4-nss-dev 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'libcurl-dev' has no installation candidate
vagrant@my_box $ # I pick gnu implementation version 4.
vagrant@my_box $ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
...
vagrant@my_box $
```

See all versions:

```
$ aptitude versions libcurl
Package libcurl-ocaml:
p   0.5.3-2build3                      precise        500

Package libcurl-ocaml-dev:
p   0.5.3-2build3                      precise        500

Package libcurl-ocaml-dev:i386:
p   0.5.3-2build3                      precise        500

Package libcurl-ocaml:i386:
p   0.5.3-2build3                      precise        500

Package libcurl3:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
i   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.15                                100
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

......

Package libcurl3-gnutls:i386:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

......

Package libcurl4-gnutls-dev:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
i   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

Package libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500
......

$ # see only curl4 related stuff
$ aptitude versions libcurl4
Package libcurl4-gnutls-dev:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
i   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

Package libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

Package libcurl4-nss-dev:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

Package libcurl4-nss-dev:i386:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

Package libcurl4-openssl-dev:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500

Package libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386:
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4                    precise        500
p   7.22.0-3ubuntu4.17                 precise-securi 500
$
$
```

If you don't name of dev lib you can do a blind search like (`grep`s for virtual packages):

```
$ aptitude search curl | grep dev | grep ^v
v   libcurl-dev                     -
v   libcurl-dev:i386                -
v   libcurl-ocaml-dev-g55y9         -
v   libcurl-ocaml-dev-owsj4:i386    -
v   libcurl-ssl-dev                 -
v   libcurl-ssl-dev:i386            -
v   libcurl3-dev                    -
v   libcurl3-dev:i386               -
v   libcurl3-gnutls-dev             -
v   libcurl3-gnutls-dev:i386        -
v   libcurl3-nss-dev                -
v   libcurl3-nss-dev:i386           -
v   libcurl3-openssl-dev            -
v   libcurl3-openssl-dev:i386       -
v   libcurl4-dev                    -
v   libcurl4-dev:i386               -
v   libghc-curl-dev-1.3.7-134ce:i38 -
v   libghc-curl-dev-1.3.7-26a38     -
v   libghc-download-curl-dev-0.1.3. -
v   libghc-download-curl-dev-0.1.3. -
v   libghc-hxt-curl-dev-9.1.1-66e48 -
v   libghc-hxt-curl-dev-9.1.1-66e48 -
$
```